# Length of sides of triangles in terms of x and d

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I came across this problem and couldn't work out how to solve it. The problem is to find r2 and r1 in terms of x and d.

[image: Problem diagram]

I tried using some trigonometry (cosine formula) and Pythagoras' theorem but couldn't make anything of it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Think about ratios between outer and inner triangle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique solution except to establish the equation

$$\sqrt{r_2^2-d^2}=\sqrt{r_1^2-d^2}+x$$

Comment: @AlphaCommie: just to expand a little on this answer, if you extend the bottom line and you choose a segment of length $x$ somewhere else, the values of $r_1$ and $r_2$ will both change. But the equation in this answer is still valid.